# how to make the output file in a specified location after running ProcessBuilder("executable.exe", "InputFile").start()

Tags: java

I want to use `Process process = new ProcessBuilder("executable.exe", "InputFile").start()` to run `executable.exe`. After running this file, it has a output file which will be stored in a default location, but I want to make a output file stored in the location I specified. I would like to know how to do it programmatically?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where you're having a problem.

Comment: Just try to look at the documentation. Hint: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` has a [`directory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29) method which sets the working directory

```
builder.directory(new File("/path/to/location"));
```